# What is the authorization for reach and frequency campaign?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I was tasked with fetching estimates for cost per click, impressions, reach, total spend, etc.
I'm trying to use the reachfrequencyprediction API, but after I execute the request I get the following error:

You do not have permission to run a reach and frequency campaign.

I tried searching on Facebook Ads Documentation but didn't find the permission you need to have to use it.

I've read the restrictions on using this feature https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachandfrequency/#restrictions and I don't seem to have any issues with that.

I've attached my code, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
/**
  * Method that creates the campaign and returns its id
  * Finally these estimates will be saved through the controller ReportController@store_meta
  */
public function crea_simulazione(StoreMetaReportRequest $request)
{

    echo "<pre>";
    // var_dump($request->all());die;

    $campaign = new Campaign(null, $this->account->id);
    $campaign->setData([
        CampaignFields::NAME => "Campagna " . uniqid(),
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE => $request->input('obiettivo'),
        CampaignFields::SPECIAL_AD_CATEGORIES => array(),
    ]);
    $campaign->create([
        Campaign::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Campaign::STATUS_PAUSED
    ]);

    echo "Campagna creata: " . $campaign->id . "\n";

    $fieldsAdSet = [
        'name' => "Ad Set " . uniqid(),
        'type_budget' => $request->input('type_budget'),
        'budget' => $request->input('importo'),
        'targeting' => $request->input('tags'),
        'luogo' => $request->input('paese_ads'),
        'age_min' => $request->input('min_eta'),
        'age_max' => $request->input('max_eta'),
        'start_ads' => $request->input('start_ads'),
        'end_ads' => $request->input('end_ads'),
        'genere' => $request->input('genere'),
        'page_id' => $request->input('pagina_facebook'),
        'billing_event' => $request->input('obiettivo'),
        'opt_goal' => $request->input('optimization_goal'),
        'country_code' => $request->input('country_ads'),
        'region_code' => $request->input('region_ads'),
        'tags_values' => $request->input('tags_values')
    ];
    $tags = [];
    foreach ($fieldsAdSet['tags_values'] as $key => $value) {
        $tags[] = ['id' => $value['id'], 'name' => $value['value']];
    }

    $fields = array(
        AdSetFields::NAME => $fieldsAdSet['name'],
        // AdSetFields::OPTIMIZATION_GOAL => $fieldsAdSet['billing_event'],
        // AdSetFields::BILLING_EVENT => $fieldsAdSet['opt_goal'],
        //inserisco questi due però sono da togliere e sostituire con quello che viene fornito da fronted.
        AdSetFields::OPTIMIZATION_GOAL => AdSetOptimizationGoalValues::REACH,
        AdSetFields::BILLING_EVENT => AdSetBillingEventValues::IMPRESSIONS,
        AdSetFields::BID_AMOUNT => 2,
        AdSetFields::DESTINATION_TYPE => AdSetDestinationTypeValues::WEBSITE,
        AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET => intval($fieldsAdSet['budget']) * 100,
        AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => $campaign->id,
        AdSetFields::TARGETING => (new Targeting())->setData(array(
            TargetingFields::GEO_LOCATIONS => array(
                'cities' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '1188733',
                        'radius' => 20,
                        'distance_unit' => 'kilometer'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            TargetingFields::USER_OS => array('iOS', 'Android', 'Windows'),
            TargetingFields::INTERESTS => $tags,
            TargetingFields::AGE_MIN => $fieldsAdSet['age_min'],
            TargetingFields::AGE_MAX => $fieldsAdSet['age_max'] - 20,
            TargetingFields::GENDERS => $fieldsAdSet['genere'] == 'all' ? [1, 2] : [$fieldsAdSet['genere']]
        )),
    );

   /**
      * I define the type of campaign.
      * If the budget type is daily then the spending limit that Facebook will set is daily with the aim of keeping it lower and lower.
      * While if it's lifetime you're telling Facebook to optimize the AdSet to get the lowest possible cost without daily budget limits.
      */
    if ($fieldsAdSet['type_budget'] == 'day') {
        $fields[AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET] = $fieldsAdSet['budget'] * 100; // Converto in centesimi perché altrimenti non lo accetta
        $fields[AdSetFields::BID_STRATEGY] = AdSetBidStrategyValues::LOWEST_COST_WITH_BID_CAP;
    } else if ($fieldsAdSet['type_budget'] == 'lifetime') {
        $fields[AdSetFields::BID_AMOUNT] = $fieldsAdSet['budget'] * 100; // Converto in centesimi perché altrimenti non lo accetta
        $fields[AdSetFields::BID_STRATEGY] = AdSetBidStrategyValues::LOWEST_COST_WITHOUT_CAP;
    }

    $this->reachfrequency($fieldsAdSet['billing_event'],$fields,$campaign->id);
    echo "End reach frequency\n";
    die;
}
public function reachfrequency($obbiettivo,$arr,$idCamapagna)
{
    $a = [
        'budget' => $arr[AdSetFields::DAILY_BUDGET],
        'day_parting_schedule' => [[
            'start_minute' => 360,
            'end_minute' => 1440,
            'days' => array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        ]],
        'destination_id' => "1730870867215691", // Page id - Brain computing
        'frequency_cap' => 2,
        'interval_frequency_cap_reset_period' => 48,
        'objective' => $obbiettivo,
        'optimization_goal' => $arr[AdSetFields::OPTIMIZATION_GOAL],
        'prediction_mode' => 1,
        'reach' => 1000000,
        'start_time' => (new DateTime('+1 day'))->getTimestamp(),
        'end_time' => (new DateTime('+8 day'))->getTimestamp(),
        'target_spec' => [
            'geo_locations' => [
                'countries' => ['IT'],
            ],
            'age_min' => 18,
            'age_max' => 65,
        ],
        'campaign_group_id' => $idCamapagna,
    ];
    $esito = Api::instance()->call('/' . env('FACEBOOK_ACCOUNT_ID_SANBOX') . "/reachfrequencypredictions", RequestInterface::METHOD_POST, $a);
    var_dump($esito);
    die;
}
```

I'm using a SandBox account, could this be why?

Comment: R&F is not open to everyone. Based on previous contacts with them, it seems that FB enables R&F based on ad spend and brand basis.